# can't comment on post

Tags: discussion

I followed directions & signed in via my Google account, but your site still won't let me comment.  I wanted to post that Mike Tang's solution re: installing ia32-libs actually worked like a charm in my Ubuntu 14.04 environment, but need to change 'raring' to 'trusty'!

Comment: You need reputation points to comment. You can earn them by asking and answering questions. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 3):

As it says on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) help page (linked from the Help link at the top of each page), in the section about commenting:

> *You can always comment on your own questions and answers. Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post.*

So if it was your question then you can leave a comment, but if it was someone else's question then you have to wait until you've earned 50 reputation before you can do so.